# unit testing using phantomjs, selenium-webdriver,nodejs and chai-webdriver assertion lib

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, chai

What I'm trying to do is to run small unit testing on my machine. I have all required node packages and phantomjs driver installed to my PATH.

```
var sw = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new sw.Builder()
.withCapabilities(sw.Capabilities.phantomjs())
.build()

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiWebdriver = require('chai-webdriver');
chai.use(chaiWebdriver(driver));

driver.get("https://www.npmjs.org/package/chai-webdriver");
setTimeout(function(){
    chai.expect('#content').dom.to.be.visible().then(function(){
        console.log("content visible");
    });
driver.quit();
},3000);
```

Running the above code,

```
 node fileName.js
```

Gives me result like this.

```
 /Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1643
  throw error;
        ^
Error: Selector #content matches nothing
at /Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/chai-webdriver/node_modules/webdriver-sizzle/lib/webdriver_sizzle.js:17:13
at /Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1243:15
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1539:20)
at notify (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:362:12)
at notifyAll (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:331:7)
at resolve (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:309:7)
at reject (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:439:5)
at /Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1243:15
at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1539:20)
at notify (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:362:12)
==== async task ====
WebDriver.call(function)
at webdriver.WebDriver.call (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:517:15)
at webdriver.WebDriver.findElementInternal_ (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:728:15)
at webdriver.WebDriver.findElement (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:706:17)
at one (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/chai-webdriver/node_modules/webdriver-sizzle/lib/webdriver_sizzle.js:15:22)
at /Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/chai-webdriver/lib/index.js:58:18
at Assertion.<anonymous> (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/chai-webdriver/lib/index.js:72:16)
at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as visible] (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:40:25)
at null._onTimeout (/Users/r558268/Documents/sandbox/assertionExample.js:30:43)
at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Now here is the thing.. if I save as the url [npmjs.org/chai-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.org/package/chai-webdriver) onto my machine and run the same test, then it passes without any errors.

I'm not able to figure out why.. can anyone please help me out on this.. MUCH APPRECIATED! Thank you.

Comment: Does increasing the timeout in `setTimeout` do anything? Are you sure the page is loaded in 3 seconds?

Comment: @ArtjomB. setTimeout actually doesnt make any difference though. I'm trying just to on safer side..saying after the page loads.. then run test. I'm wondering why it passes on local html but not on live url..

Comment: @ArtjomB. I ran into few forums saying phantomjs doesnt have bind method.. I tried the live page with es6-shim.js linked to it.. but still not result.

Comment: **Is there anyone help me out on this... **

Comment: I'm not familiar with the selenium-webdriver API. You would need to execute this [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521) on the page with `driver.executeScript`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks!! But still doesn/t works.. same error.

Comment: Two things about your code sample. One is silly, but since you asked the question back in July, the NPM website has changed -- now `#content` doesn't exist on the page anymore, so this is actually the error that you should expect to be getting. But if you change it to something that *does* exist on the page, like `#readme`, it still fails.

Looking a little bit deeper: it looks like it works if you use chrome instead of phantomJS, so long as you have chromedriver in your path. Try this:

`withCapabilities(sw.Capabilities.chrome())`